# Laravel/Swoole - Resolving a class in a task worker is very slow

Tags: laravel, concurrency, swoole, openswoole

I'm utilising Swoole concurrency in a Laravel project.

In the task worker I need to resolve a class (because the function passed to the task worker needs to be serialized, I can't pass the class to the worker - let me know if I'm incorrect in this assumption).

The resolution of this class takes ~400ms. When resolving the same class outside of the task worker , is is less than a millisecond to resolve.

I wanted to understand what is causing this, and if there are any approaches or patterns that could achieve a resolution in <1ms.

```
// <1ms
$class = resolve(MyClass::class);

Octane::concurrently([
  fn () => self::func(),
  ...
]);

private static function func()
{
  // 400ms - Why is this?
  $class = resolve(MyClass::class);
}
```

Thanks in advance!